# Why can't my cypher query use multiple variable-length paths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the following graph, how can I match both Rule 1 and Rule 2, using the green nodes "Qualification" and "New York" as conditions?

Help me understand why the following Cypher query does not work:

```
MATCH 
(r:Rule),
(r)-[w1:When*]->(c:State{instanceName:"New York"}),
(r)-[w2:When*]->(c2:Service{instanceName:"Qualification"})
RETURN * LIMIT 50
```

This query returns only Rule 2, not Rule 1.

Each of these queries works individually and returns the expected results:

```
MATCH 
(r:Rule),
(r)-[w2:When*]->(c2:Service{instanceName:"Qualification"})
RETURN * LIMIT 50

MATCH 
(r:Rule),
(r)-[w1:When*]->(c:State{instanceName:"New York"})
RETURN * LIMIT 50
```

[image: Sample graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query does not return rule 1 due to the [uniqueness](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/introduction/uniqueness/#cypherdoc-uniqueness) of relationships in a single `MATCH` clause. In your example, the `When` relationship between `Rule 1` and `Instance` is the same for both paths, and only one of them is returned.

To work around this, use two separate `MATCH` clauses.

```
MATCH 
  (r:Rule),
  (r)-[w1:When*]->(c:State {instanceName: "New York"}),
MATCH
  (r)-[w2:When*]->(c2:Service {instanceName: "Qualification"})
RETURN *
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Somtehing like that with separate patterns :

```
MATCH (r:Rule)
MATCH (r)-[w1:When*]->(c:State{instanceName:"New York"})
MATCH (r)-[w2:When*]->(c2:Service{instanceName:"Qualification"})
RETURN * LIMIT 50
```